# How to delete the first element in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a function delete() that takes a linked list and deletes the Kth element from the list.  My code is below.

```
public void delete(int k){
  Node current = head;
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
      if(current == null || current.next == null){ //check if list is empty or k is out of bounds

          throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
          }
      else 
      {
          current = current.next; // Move pointer to k position
      }
  }
  remove(current.item);
  N--;  
  }

public void remove(E e) {
if (e == null)
  throw new NullPointerException();

// (*) special case (2/one node with e)
if (head != null && head.item.equals(e)) {
  head = null;
  N--;
}
else { // (*) general case (3) -- this also covers the case for empty list
  Node temp;
  // Step 1: bring temp to one node before the node with e.
  for (temp = head; temp != null && !temp.next.item.equals(e);
       temp = temp.next) {} // empty body
  // Step 2: if temp is still in the list, then remove
  if (temp != null) {
    temp.next = temp.next.next;
    --N;
  }
}
```

}

So far my code works as expected when I run a command such as `lst1.delete(1)` or `lst1.delete(2)` in main.  However, when I run `lst1.delete(0)`, it deletes the entire linked list.  I cannot figure out why `lst1.delete(0)` is deleting the entire linked list, but I think is has something to do with the for-loop.  The for-loop is loops up until one less than k.  If I pass in 0, then perhaps it is deleting the head entry point, which is deleting the entire list?

My question is, can anybody please tell me how I can change my code so that when I run `lst1.delete(0)`, it just deletes the first element in the linked list, and not the entire linked list?

Comment: When you run lst1.delete(1), how long is the remaining list?  I guess only a single element?  If that's expected, then deleting everything from head will delete the entire list.

Comment: Updated to show what goes on in `remove` function.  @brianestey, when I run lst1.delete(1), it removes the element in position 1 in the linked list.  All other items stay.  So the number of remaining items in the linked list is just decremented by one.

Comment: `head = null` looks suspicious.  That's not just if there is a single item, that's if you are deleting the first item.

Comment: The for-loop is loops up until one less than k. If I pass in 0, then perhaps it is deleting the head entry point, which is deleting the entire list?

Comment: If you pass 0, it never loops.  It sets `current` to `head` and then calls `remove(head.item)` which then matches your condition `head.item.equals(head.item)`.

Comment: Where does the variable N come from?

Comment: @AchinthaGunasekara N is a variable stored in the main class `private int N;     // number of elements stored in the list`

Comment: @brianestey, that makes sense, but then why does it delete the whole linked list?

Comment: If `head` is `null`, when you loop using `for(temp=head; temp != null...)`, you'll never have anything in your list...

Comment: @Sammy, I did not write the remove() method.  That method was written by my professor and I am supposed to design the delete() method around it.  I assumed it was written correctly, but perhaps the professor made an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another method that does not even call the remove method.  Since I was not the one who originally wrote the remove method, I prefer the code below over the others only because it stays within its self as far as method calling goes.

```
public void delete(int k){
  //instance variable
  Node current = head;

  if(current == null || current.next == null){ //check if list is empty

      throw new NullPointerException();
      }

  if (k < 0 || k >= size()){                  // check if k is out of bounds

      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }

  if (k == 0){                                // this handles k = 0 condition
      head = head.next;
  }

  else

  for (int i = 0; i < k-1; i++){              // otherwise, if K != 0,
      current = current.next;                 // move pointer to k position

  }

  if (current != null) {
        current.next = current.next.next;
  }

  N--;  

  }
```

This gave me the output I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue.
You are setting

```
head = null;
```

if the item to remove is the head, but what you should do is,

```
if(head.next() != null) {
    head = head.next();
}
else {

    head = null;
}
```

This will point the head to head + 1 item, unless head is the only item in the list. in that case we should set head to null.

```
public void delete(int k) {

    Node current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){

        if(current == null || current.next == null) { //check if list is empty or k is out of bounds

            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else {

            current = current.next; // Move pointer to k position
        }
    }

    remove(current.item);

    N--;  
}

public void remove(E e) {

    if (e == null) {

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    // (*) special case (2/one node with e)
    if (head != null && head.item.equals(e)) {

        //Your issue was here
        if(head.next() != null) {

            head = head.next();
        }
        else {

            head = null;
        }

        N--;
    }
    else { // (*) general case (3) -- this also covers the case for empty list

        Node temp;

        // Step 1: bring temp to one node before the node with e.
        for (temp = head; temp != null && !temp.next.item.equals(e);

            temp = temp.next) {} // empty body

            // Step 2: if temp is still in the list, then remove
            if (temp != null) {

                temp.next = temp.next.next;
                    --N;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: refer to the comment at head = head.next();

Answer (score 0):

You problem is here

```
if (head != null && head.item.equals(e)) {
     head = null;
     N--;
}
```

if you use `lst1.delete(0)` then `head.item.equals(e)` become true as you pass `head` to `remove()`. Then your entire linked removed.

One fix would be

```
 if (head != null && head.item.equals(e)&&head.next==null) {
     head = null;
     N--;
}
```

Here extra check `head.next==null` ensure that there have only one element in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

1) delete(0). delete never enters loop because i less than k is true straight away. So you remove head.item. 
2) Then remove special case 2 sets head = null.

That's 2 mistakes. No offence but your code is a mess. Sit down with diagrams and try puzzling it from scratch again. Someone else doing it for you will teach you nothing except how to give up on a programming problem early.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  As mentioned above, I did not write the remove() method. That method was written by my professor and I am supposed to design the delete() method around it. I assumed it was written correctly, but perhaps the professor made an error

Comment: Professors make mistakes. They can be careless or in a rush. Point it out nicely if your professor is decent and you'll be noticed in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

This reason is because when k = 0, the loop is never entered. As a result, `current` is not updated to point to the right one.